# State nulls out inside render function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component where I make an API call to get data pertinent to an user. Here's my code,

```
class Header extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { user: null };

  }

  componentDidMount() {

    getUserData(xobni_api).then((data) =>{
      this.setState({user : data});
      console.log(this.state.user);//A


    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="header">
        <Masthead user={this.state.user.fullName} />//B
        <PrimaryNav/>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Header;
```

At line `A`, I can render the details of the user, while at line `B` user is `null` and I'm getting an error. What am I missing. I've tried making the API calls inside both `componentDidMount()` and `componentWillMount()`. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you include the error log?

Comment: Likely, what's happening is that your child components are rendering before your ajax request is done executing. Maybe using compomentWillReceiveProps would help there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first time your component renders `this.state.user` is `null`, right? That's what you set it as in your constructor. Therefore `this.state.user.fullName` is equivalent to `null.fullName` which will crash.

You either need to make your initial state representative of the shape of your `user` object, or you need to do a null check before rendering the component:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="header">
      {this.state.user && // <-- check if truthy
        <Masthead user={this.state.user.fullName} />
      }
      <PrimaryNav />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Because you're doing an ajax request, you can also use this opportunity to display a loading indicator:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="header">
      {!this.state.user && // <-- if user is still null
        <div>Loading...</div>
      }

      {this.state.user && // <-- check if truthy
        <Masthead user={this.state.user.fullName} />
      }
      <PrimaryNav />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the initial render, `this.state.user` is `null`, and you were trying to get `fullname` property from a `null` object, so you get an error.

To fix, change line `B` to:

```
{this.state.user && <Masthead user={this.state.user.fullName} />}
```